# How to disable samba shared folder password prompt

Tags: windows, samba, password, share

I have shared a samba folder on ubuntu desktop. Is there a way to disable ubuntu shared folder password prompt when accessed from windows?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check "Remember My password" check box.

[image]

Then check "Reconnect at logon"

[image]

Comment: won't it prompt even after rebooting the windows machine?

Comment: Yes, but first unmount the mounted shared location, then mount it again with checking "Remember my password" and "Reconnect at logon" checkbox's, after that you can try rebooting your windows machine it won't prompt again.

Comment: I have checked the way you suggested on my xp vm. I don't know why it's still prompting for the password after every reboot. I've checked it for 6-7 times rebooting xp vm and it kept on prompting for the password.

Comment: No, actually it should be on xp physical machine. I'm just trying to access ubuntu shared folder on my xp virtual machine.

Comment: I'm thinking if it works on the vm then it will definitely works on the real windows machine

Comment: That will be true but I think it depends on what virtual machine you are using and the way you are mapping the shared folder. i'm using a deferent method sharing between ubuntu and xp inside Virtualbox. anyhow i don't know exactly your virtual machine problem.

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox VMs. I'm checking in the VMs because I can't restart real machines right now as it's running many virtual servers and so I'm trying it on my local vms. I'll definitely let you know once I restart the windows machine.